# mdadm software RAID doesn't load at boot

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I'm using mdadm to create a raid1 mirror across two disks. I can create my /dev/md5 array perfectly using the tools, but it does not automatically reload my /dev/md5 when I restart, I need to manually recreate the array.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure your partitions are of type `fd: Linux raid autodetect`.  Also, create the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file, the easiest way is with:

```
mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

after sucessfully building the array.

Comment: +1 I've had to do this before also.

Comment: you should probably append (>>) to mdadm.conf.  I think this is also required if you are using whole disks instead of partitions.